# Datetime value getting reset in wcf service on using as a web reference and not with using as a service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a WCF Service with operation as follow:

```
    public void setNotifications(List<AnnouncementDataContract> announcements)
    {
        foreach(AnnouncementDataContract item in announcements)
        {
            ent.InsertAnnouncements(item.Anc_Text, item.Anc_Date);
        }
    }
```

When I add this WCF service as a  webreference in my MVC application and calls the method as follow:

```
       MyService.Service1 proxy = new MyService.Service1();
       Collection<MyService.AnnouncementDataContract> dc = new 
                              Collection<MyService.AnnouncementDataContract>();
        MyService.AnnouncementDataContract dc1 = new              
        MyService.AnnouncementDataContract();
        dc1.anc_Date = System.DateTime.Now;
        dc1.anc_Text = "Announcement1";
        dc.Add(dc1);
        proxy.setNotifications(dc.ToArray());
```

The value in each item for "announcements" at the service operation is reset and i get it as min datetime value not the one i have sent from my MVC application on calling the operation.

But when I add this WCF service as a  service reference in my MVC application and calls the operation, it works fine and the correct value of datetime is obtained at service.

Comment: Can you show us the `AnnouncementDataContract` class definition? (Have you added a `[DataMember]` attribute to the `anc_Date` property?)

Comment: It might have something to do with the the way the proxy is generated - I believe add service reference uses svcutil, whereas add web reference uses the older ASMX auto-generator (forgetting the name right now).  In any case, service reference is how you add a reference to WCF.  Add web reference is there for backwords-compatibility with legacy ASMX web services.

Comment: On an unrelated note: you should really require the client to pass UTC values (e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow`) with their announcements. Otherwise you'll end up in an unnecessary mess if client and server (and possibly other clients reading the announcements), having configured different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. It is because the generated proxy code for your AnnouncementDataContract class also creates a property called Anc_DateSpecified, which has to be set to true.
This is the case for all value types.